# Loose coupling in sequence diagrams

Tags: uml

I have a question about UML diagrams.

Can be displayed relations between loose coupled components on sequence diagrams?
It is required in loose coupled environment (MQ) or optional?

For example, component "A" put some message into queue "X", then component "B" takes this message from queue "X". Should be this relation displayed on sequence diagram?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one sequence diagram is not good place for it because according your question there are TWO asynchronous interactions.

The best way is to use TWO sequence diagrams or state chart diagram (you can use it to describe how queue works)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. A sequence diagram demonstrates how components/classes interact in a use case. As long as the resulting diagram clearly demonstrated the interaction you are modelling then you should show the interactions. If the diagram looks very cluttered and difficult to read then you could split in to 2 seperate diagrams; first shows 'A' put the message on the queue and the second diagram shows 'B' pull the message off the queue. Ultimately, you need to make the concepts in the diagram easy for somebody to read, so less clutter the better.